# Azure Managed Disk not showing when trying to attach to VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-disk

I have a premium Azure Managed Disk (SSD) in the same region as a Windows VM, but when I go to attach it via the Azure portal (settings -> Disks -> + Add data disk) the drop down under name says "No managed disk available" (see below). What do I need to do?

[image]

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow (as it's not programming-related), and likely fits better on ServerFault. That said: You cannot attach premium disks to a VM unless you are using a `xS`-based sku (e.g. a DS14 vs a D14). Which sku type did you try attaching to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Premium storage, you'll need a Premium Storage enabled VM size like the DS-series or GS-series virtual machine. You cannot use premium storage disks with VM series that are not Premium Storage-compatible. For details, see [Premium Storage: High-Performance Storage for Azure Virtual Machine Workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/premium-storage?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem after I had detached a disk from one VM and tried to attach it to another VM.  Apparently those changes take some time to propagate through the system, and the solution for me was to log out of the Azure portal and then log back in again.

Comment: this worked for me. unreal.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and it turned to be because I had chosen the incorrect resource group. Under Basics tab, you need to check the resource group where the Disk belongs to and make the appropriate selection. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: This is weird. But it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

**It's a 3 step process**, once you **create** & **attach**, you need to **mount** it as well.
Follow the instructions presented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal#connect-to-the-linux-vm-to-mount-the-new-disk).

```
lsblk -o NAME,HCTL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT | grep -i "sd"
```

This command will show you if you have the disk or not.

**Before:**
[image: disc with-out mount]

**After:**
[image: disc with mount]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and I checked so many times if the vm would support premium LRS and mine did, but still not seeing the disk I just created.
I solved it by just refreshing the whole portal after creating snapshot disk, and then every disk that I can possibly attached shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and I checked so many times if the vm would support premium LRS and mine did, but still not seeing the disk I just created. Also tried to refresh the whole portal but still issue didn't fixed. After that i checked my disk was not created in availability zone. And my VM was in availability zone 1. once i created the disk in availability 1. it appeared in my new VM data disk.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to stop the VM? When VM is running you cannot attach existing disks.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a problem with Availaibility zones. My VM was located in West Europe (Zone 1), the disk was just West Europe. I had to recreate the disk via Snapshot (create Zone-redundant snapshot), on creating the new disk from the snapshot you can select the correct availability zone (same as the VM you're trying to attach it to)